# settings api callback functions won't display?

Tags: settings-api

Hi guys I have been working with the settings API and my code won't run. I have an options page called "kaipo", and the callback function in that add_options_page function will output "hii" from kaipo_menu_callback function. That is the only part of my code that actually runs. When I declare my section the function that should output "hellooooo" does not print and also my input fields does not display. i.e the functions Kaipo_footer_message_display and Kaipo_message_display does not print anything. Have I registered something wrongly? please help me!!

```
 <?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Kaipo2
* Plugin URI: http://www.kaipochat.com
* Description: Chat By Interest
* Version: 1.0
* Author: JSL
* Author URI: http://www.kaipochat.com
* License: GPL2
*/

function Kaipo_add_options_page(){

    add_options_page(
        'Kaipo', //text to be displayed in title bar
        'Kaipo', //text displayed to menu
        'administrator', //required capability to users
        'kaipo_menu_page', //slug
        'Kaipo_menu_callback' //callback function
    );
}
//options page display
function Kaipo_menu_callback(){
    echo "hii";
}
//Register a new settings field on the General Settings page of the WordPress dashboard

function Kaipo_initialize_settings_field(){

    //introduce section rendered through the options page
    add_settings_section(
        'footer_section', //ID of field
        'Footer Options', //text used to label field
        'Kaipo_footer_message_display', //callback function to render the field
        'kaipo_menu_page' //ID of the page on which this section is rendered (must match the slug of add_options_page())
    );

    //define settings field
    add_settings_field(
        'footer_message', //ID of the field
        'Footer Message', //Text to label the field
        'Kaipo_message_display', //call back function to render the field
        'kaipo_menu_page',   //the page on which we are rendering the field
        'footer_section' //the section to which we are adding the settings
    );

    //register the 'footer_message' setting with the 'General' section
    register_setting(
        'footer_section',
        'footer_message'
    );
}//end of function

add_action('admin_init', 'Kaipo_initialize_settings_field');

//options page section display
function Kaipo_footer_message_display(){
  echo "helloooooo";
}

//renders the input field for Footer Message in the General Settings section
function Kaipo_message_display(){
    echo '<input type="text" name="footer_message" id="footer_message" value="' . get_option('footer_message') . '" />';
}




add_action('admin_menu', 'Kaipo_add_options_page');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to print your settings fields in `Kaipo_menu_callback`, something like:

```
<?php

function Kaipo_menu_callback() {
    ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <h2>Kaipo</h2>
    <form action="options.php" method="post"><?php

        do_settings_sections( 'kaipo_menu_page' );
        settings_fields( 'kaipo_menu_page' );
        submit_button();

    ?></form>
</div>

<?php
}
```

I would strongly suggest reading the [settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) in detail.